# how to get an AudioClip's BPM in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my project, there is a variable that is planned to contain the current AudioClip's current BPM. But I don't know of any ways to measure an AudioClip's BPM.
I've been searching for a solution, but everything I found were about beat detection.

Comment: @derHugo yes, I did. But most were about beat detection, for me at least.

Comment: in your eyes what exactly is the difference between `measure an AudioClip's BPM` (= **Beats** per minute) and `beat detection` ... ?

Comment: @derHugo you have a point... I'll try to use it then. But I dont think it will be very accurate.

Comment: don't complain until you tried ;) BPM is always an estimation .. except of course you are the maker of the clip ;)

Comment: @derHugo I know I know, but it would be nice if the bpm was accurate. Let's hope it is.